# Reflection in Android is not working

Tags: java, android, reflection

I tried using reflection to use a custom List View for an App with target api level 7. The necessary fileds are only available from api level 9 so I attempted to fix that via reflection.

I need to find the protected Method View.overScrollBy( int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,boolean). When i call

```
View.getDeclaredMethods()
```

and iterate over the Method[] array i find it, but when I try

```
View.class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class...< ? > paramTypes)
```

I get a NoSuchMethodException. I compared the hard coded Method Name and parameterType values with the values extracted from the method (found via iteration) and they are identical...

```
private boolean initCompatibility() 
{
Method[] methods = View.class.getDeclaredMethods();
try {
    // The name of the Method i am looking for;
    String OVERSCROLL_S = "overScrollBy";
    for (Method meth : methods) {
        if (meth.getName().equals(OVERSCROLL_S)) {
            mListView_overScrollBy = meth;
            break;
            // method found
        }
    }

    // Params for getDeclaredMethod(…)
    String methodName = "overScrollBy";
    Class[] methodParams =  {  Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, 
            Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, 
            Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE };

    // works
    Method test =  View.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,methodParams);
    // fails
    View.class.getDeclaredMethod(mListView_overScrollBy.getName(), 
               mListView_overScrollBy.getParameterTypes());

    /*
    * I also tried this way around and again the first worked and the second
    * failed, so the input arguments are not the problem...
    * View.class.getDeclaredMethod( mListView_overScrollBy.getName(), 
    *                           mListView_overScrollBy.getParameterTypes() );
    * Method test =  View.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,methodParams);
    */

    return true;
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the call always works the first time and the does not the second time. Interestingly it also fails when i call only once for View.class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class...< ? > paramTypes) and it does not make any difference whether i use the hard coded input values or the one extracted from the method I am looking for...

Does anybody know what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: Look at my answer. Could you confirm if your exception is thrown in both debug and run modes?

Comment: Stupid question time!  Is this the real code that you are running?  Any chance the `View` you investigate earlier is a different class then the one later?  Different `import` since it's a common class name.

Comment: Another stupid question: Do you get an output at the printStackTrace? I just run your exact code in an emulator, and didn't get an output. Also, when debuging Android apps in eclipse, the line numbers esp. with returns are not correct. So after the 2nd getDeclaredMethod, the IP points to the return statement in the catch block, even if no exception was thrown at all! (encountered such behaviour quite often)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very interesting, but it is not Android-specific, I think.

I wrote this small test in plain Java:

```
    public class ReflectionTest {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Method[] m = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : m) {
                System.out.println(method.getName());
            }               

            try {
                Method m1 = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("d0", int.class, boolean.class);
                if(m1 != null){
                    System.out.println("m1 found!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            try {
                Method m2 = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("d0", Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE);
                if(m2 != null){
                    System.out.println("m2 found!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            try {
                Class<?>[] carr = m[1].getParameterTypes();
                Method m3 = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("d0", carr);
                if(m3 != null){
                    System.out.println("m3 found!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        public void d0(int a, boolean b){

        }
    }
```

In eclipse, if I debug it, the three m1,m2 and m3 are printed. However, if I run it, a `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown when trying to get m3.

UPDATES:

- Tested running with jre 7 under linux, and all three m1,m2 and m3 were printed. Perhaps is a problem with jre6? Or is eclipse run configuration?
- Changed `carr` declaration to use method 0 instead of 1:  `Class<?>[] carr = m[0].getParameterTypes();` as Gray suggested. Now it runs ok but throws exception in debug mode. This means different method order for the returned array `m`.
- Update #2 confirmed, I've included a for loop to print the method names. In run mode the order of the method array is reversed compared to debug mode.

Comment: Your test works fine for me under JRE6 under MacOSX.  Maybe a particular JRE version number?

Comment: Have same problem: in eclipse works when debuging, throws exception when running. Win7 64bit, JRE 1.6.0_26-b03 and JDK 1.6.0_20-b02. getDeclaredMethods must have a problem, as it searches for `d0([Ljava.lang.String)`, so a method with String[] argument

Comment: @Gray That maybe the case. I'm running JRE 1.6.0_07-b06, eclipse 3.6 helios, Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: @king_nak thats the exception i'm getting too. Is there a site to search a DB of JRE bugs?

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.2. java version "1.6.0_26", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)

Comment: Here's the release note index for 1.6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html

Comment: Oh wait!!! Maybe there is a different method order.  Maybe `main` is m[1] in some architectures.  That would explain the `Ljava.lang.String`/.  Try: `Class<?>[] carr = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethod("d0").getParameterTypes();`

Comment: It may have to do with the top 6 bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6434149

Comment: So debug has a different method order from `getDeclaredMethods();`.  Either that or debug injects some fake methods in there or something.

Comment: @Gray is the method order, I've just tested it. Updated code with a method printout.